# Can std::string be used without #include <string>?

Tags: c++, stdstring

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::string s = "hello";
    std::cout << s.size() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

To my surprise, I can compile and run it with `clang++`, though I even don't add `#include <string>`.

So, is it necessary to add `#include <string>` in order to use `std::string` ?

Answer (score 28):

Your implementation's `iostream` header includes `string`. This is not something which you can or should rely on. If you want to use `std::string`, you should always `#include <string>`, otherwise your program might not run on different implementations, or even in later versions of your current one.

Answer (score 11):

In short: yes, it is necessary.

Parts of standard library often use other parts, so `<string>` was included somehow through `<iostream>`, and your code compiles nicely.

If you accidentally decide that you don't need `<iostream>` anymore and remove that include, `<string>` will be implicitly removed, too, and you get a confusing compilation error. That's why it is a good practice to put all necessary includes.

Answer (score 5):

Some header might include other headers, but that's an implementation issue and not something you can count on. Always explicitly include the headers you need.

Answer (score 3):

iostream includes `<string>`. It ripples through.

Well actually that's implementation dependant and not a guarantee. You should explicitly include the headers you need.