# Why this code works smooth without including #include<string>, C++

Tags: c++, string

```
#include<iostream>

int main() {

std::string str = "Hello";

std::cout << str << std::endl;

return 0;

}
```

As I learned from various places, whenever you want to use `std::string` you should include string header file.

However, the code above does not require `#include<string>` to run, why is that so?

note: I am using g++ to compile it from bash terminal.

Comment: In your case, `<iostream>` apparently includes `<string>`. It is not guaranteed to work across other compilers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can std::string be used without #include <string>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33349833/can-stdstring-be-used-without-include-string)

Comment: @Brian yes, thanks, I could not find it while I searched.